# What happens with attached modifiers on overrriden functions?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to understand function overrides so far I'm understanding the concept. However, I'm wondering What happens with attached modifiers if a function is overridden? do they have to be re-attached?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following contracts:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract A {
    modifier modified() {
        revert("Modified");
        // Before
        _;
        // After
    }

    function test1() public virtual modified {
        // A.test1 body
    }
    function test2() public virtual modified {
        // A.test2 body
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function test1() public override {
        // B.test1 body
    }
    function test2() public override {
        super.test2();
        // B.test2 body
    }
}
```

First of all, when `B.test1()` overrides `A.test1()`, `B.test1()` does not automatically call the super implementation. This means that when you call `B.test1()`, `A.test1()` will never be invoked, so the `modified` modifier will not kick in.

In the case of `B.test2()`, it explicitly calls `A.test2()`. As `A.test2()` has been modified with modifier `modified`, the code inside `modified` becomes “part of” `A.test2()`. So yes, when `B.test2()` is called, it will call `A.test2()` *including* `modified`.

So no, `modified` doesn’t need to be reattached. But keep in mind that when `B.test2()` overrides the modified function `A.test2()`, the modifier is not “unattached” and “reattached” to `B.test2()`. Once `A.test2()` has been modified, the code of `A.test2()` is modified to “include” the code inside `modified`, so to speak. So the equivalent code for `B.test2()` is:

```
revert("Modified");
// Before
// A.test2 body
// After
// B.test2 body
```

and not:

```
revert("Modified");
// Before
// A.test2 body
// B.test2 body
// After
```

Deploy `B` in Remix IDE (to JavaScript VM is enough, no need to deploy to a public blockchain) and try it out. Call `B.test1()` and `B.test2()` and see what happens, and poke it around to see how it behaves. Whenever you have this type of doubt, Remix IDE is your friend.

P.S. If on the other hand you *want* the modifier behaviour to wrap the overridden function, then this could be achieved as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense

pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract A {
    modifier modified() {
        // Before
        _;
        // After
    }
    function _unmodifiedTest3() internal virtual {
        // Something
    }
    function test3() external modified {
        _unmodifiedTest3();
    }
}

contract B is A {
    function _unmodifiedTest3() internal override {
        super._unmodifiedTest3();
        // Something extra
    }
}
```

The equivalent code for `B.test3()` will be:

```
// Before
// Something
// Something extra
// After
```